# Factor to complex roots using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

I can't figure out how to factor an polynomial expression to its complex roots.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> s = symbol('s')
>>> factor(s**2+1)
 2
s  + 1
```

Comment: Does factor(s**2-1) or factor(s**2-3) work? Does sympy have support for Gauß numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `I` as an algebraic extension:

```
In [2]: factor(x**2 + 1, extension=[I])
Out[2]: (x - ⅈ)⋅(x + ⅈ)
```

Comment: You can also set `gaussian=True` to factor over the Gaussian rationals.

Comment: Thanks, an example where those don't work is: `factor(s**3 + s**2 + 1, gaussian=True)`, which is peculiar because roots(s**3 + s**2 + 1) finds all the roots.

Comment: The roots of that polynomial are not gaussian rationals.

Comment: If you always want a full factorization over C, you can just use something like `LC(polynomial, s)*Mul(*[(s - a)**r[a] for a in r])`, where `r = roots(polynomial, s)`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake, and proposing a workaround to writing out the irrational factorization!

I suppose it's worth mentioning that the `extension=I` kwarg seems to act identically to the `gaussian=True` kwarg, i.e. factors over Gaussian rationals.

Comment: Actually, you'll want to use `RootOf`. `roots` doesn't return roots that can't be expressed in radicals (either because it is impossible or because the algorithms are not implemented).