# Full factorization of polynomials over complexes with SymPy

Tags: python, math, sympy, polynomial-math

I want to fully factorize a polynom, [thus factorize it over complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

*SymPy* provide `factor` to do it, but I’m very surprised that factorization is done only over integer roots, *e.g.* :

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> z = symbols('z')
>>> factor(z**2 - 1, z)
(z - 1)*(z + 1)
>>> factor(z**2 + 1, z)
z**2 + 1
```

or

```py
>>> factor(2*z - 1, z)
2*z - 1
>>> factor(2*z - 1, z, extension=[Integer(1)/2])
2*(z - 1/2)
```

An answered question already exists : [Factor to complex roots using sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089150), and the solution given by *asmeurer* works :

```py
>>> factor(z**2 + 1, z, extension=[I])
(z - I)*(z + I)
```

but you need to specify every divisor of non-integer roots, *e.g.* :

```py
>>> factor(z**2 + 2, z, extension=[I])
z**2 + 2
>>> factor(z**2 + 2, z, extension=[I, sqrt(2)])
(z - sqrt(2)*I)*(z + sqrt(2)*I)
```

My question is : how to fully factorize a polynom (thus over complexes), without needing to give every divisor to `extension` ?

*asmeurer* gives a solution to do this :

```py
>>> poly = z**2 + 2
>>> r = roots(poly, z)
>>> LC(poly, z)*Mul(*[(z - a)**r[a] for a in r])
/      ___  \ /      ___  \
\z - \/ 2 *I/*\z + \/ 2 *I/
```

But it should exists a native way to do it, no ?
Someting like `factor(poly, z, complex=True)`.

I looked for in the [documentation of `factor`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html?highlight=factor#sympy.polys.polytools.factor), but I did not find anything.
Futhermore, `factor` can take `domain` as optional argument that I believed allows to specified the set on which the factorization is made, but not

```py
>>> factor(z**2 + 2, z, domain='Z')
 2
z  + 2
>>> factor(z**2 + 2, z, domain='R')
    /     2      \
2.0*\0.5*z  + 1.0/
>>> factor(z**2 + 2, z, domain='C')
     2
1.0*z  + 2.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain argument should work and in the case of Gaussian rationals you can also use `gaussian=True` which is equivalent to `extension=I`:

```
In [24]: factor(z**2 + 1, gaussian=True)
Out[24]: (z - ⅈ)⋅(z + ⅈ)
```

That doesn't work in your case though because the factorisation needs to be over `QQ(I, sqrt(2))` rather than `QQ(I)`. The reason that domains `'R'` and `'C'` don't work as expected is because they are inexact floating point domains rather than domains representing the real or complex numbers in the pure mathematical sense and factorisation is

The approaches above can be combined though with

```
In [28]: e = z**2 + 2

In [29]: factor(e, extension=roots(e))
Out[29]: (z - √2⋅ⅈ)⋅(z + √2⋅ⅈ)
```

Comment: That was exactly the solution I looked for !
But actually, I got this problem from another one with factorization over symbolic roots with square-roots, so I create another question : [SymPy: Factorization of polynomials over symbolic roots with combined square roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371772).
Maybe you could help me one this one too :-).