# SymPy: Factorization of polynomials over symbolic roots with combined square roots

Tags: python, math, sympy, polynomials, polynomial-math

SymPy `factor` function can factorize over symbolic roots, *e.g.* :

```py
In [1]: from sympy import *
In [2]: init_printing(use_latex=False)
In [3]: z, a, b = symbols('z a b')
In [4]: poly = expand((z - sqrt(a))*(z - sqrt(b)), z)
In [5]: poly
Out[5]: 
                       2
√a⋅√b - √a⋅z - √b⋅z + z 
In [6]: factor(poly, z)
Out[6]: (-√a + z)⋅(-√b + z)
```

but the factorization fails if `b = a` :

```py
In [10]: b = a
In [11]: poly = expand((z - sqrt(a))*(z - sqrt(b)), z)
In [12]: poly
Out[12]: 
               2
-2⋅√a⋅z + a + z 
In [13]: factor(poly, z)
Out[13]: 
               2
-2⋅√a⋅z + a + z
```

Thus, the factorization fails if the identity `sqrt(a) * sqrt(a) = a` is applied, and this identity is always applied as it is a particular instance of the identity `a**x + a**y = a**(x + y)` which is always true (cf [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#powers)).

I tried with `extension` as it works for non-integer roots (cf my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357494)), but it does not work :

```py
In [14]: roo = roots(poly, z)
In [15]: roo
Out[15]: {√a: 2}

In [16]: factor(poly, z, extension=[sqrt(a)])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CoercionFailed                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
CoercionFailed: can’t convert 1 of type <class 'sympy.polys.fields.FracElement'> from ZZ(a) to QQ<sqrt(a)>

In [17]: factor(poly, z, extension=roo)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CoercionFailed                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
CoercionFailed: can’t convert 1 of type <class 'sympy.polys.fields.FracElement'> from ZZ(a) to QQ<sqrt(a)>
```

Is there a way to factorize a polynomial over symbolic roots when such identity is applied ?

Comment: I think that's maybe a bug or otherwise at least something that could be improved. Best to open an issue https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: I followed your advice and I create the issue [#19570](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19570).

Answer (score 1):

There is a not very well documented function called `root_factors` that uses `roots` to perform factorisation:

```
In [28]: from sympy import *

In [29]: a, x = symbols('a, x')

In [30]: poly = expand((z - sqrt(a))*(z - sqrt(b)))

In [31]: poly
Out[31]: 
               2
-2⋅√a⋅z + a + z 

In [32]: factor(poly)
Out[32]: 
               2
-2⋅√a⋅z + a + z 

In [33]: from sympy.polys.polyroots import root_factors

In [34]: root_factors(poly, z)
Out[34]: [-√a + z, -√a + z]

In [35]: Mul(*root_factors(poly, z))
Out[35]: 
         2
(-√a + z)
```